# How can I make a storyboard fade in, pause, and then fade out (through code)?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I wrote the following code. It tries to create a storyboard that does the following:

1. fade in for 500ms
2. pause for 1000ms
3. fade out for 500ms

But at run time get an System.InvalidOperationException followed by the following output:

```
Additional information: Multiple animations in 
  the same containing Storyboard cannot target the
  same property on a single element.
```

This seems to suggest its trying to do all the animations at once rather than sequentially.

```
private Storyboard createStoryboard()
{
  Storyboard board = new Storyboard();

  addFadeToStoryboard(board, 0, 1, 500);
  addFadeToStoryboard(board, 1, 1, 1000);

  DoubleAnimation fadeOut = addFadeToStoryboard(board, 1, 0, 500);

  fadeOut.Completed += new EventHandler(onFadeCompleted);

  Storyboard.SetTarget(board, this);

  return board;
}

private DoubleAnimation addFadeToStoryboard(Storyboard board, 
  double fadeFrom, double fadeTo, double milliseconds)
{
  DoubleAnimation fade = new DoubleAnimation()
  {
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)),
    From = fadeFrom,
    To = fadeTo,
    RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1)
  };

  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade,
    new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

  board.Children.Add(fade);

  return fade;
}
```

How can I make it sequential? Am I misinterpreting something fundamental about storyboards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by creating my own sequencer class. It has a dependency on a LinkedList class, so you'll have to swap that out with the standard one if you want to use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace YourNamespace
{
  // An object that contains multiple storyboards, and fires off 
  // subsequent ones as they finish.

  public class StoryboardSequencer
  {
    public StoryboardSequencer()
    {
    }

    public void add(Storyboard board)
    {
      m_boards.add(board);
      board.Completed += new EventHandler(onBoardCompleted);
    }

    // Starts the storyboard from the first.
    // If already started, this call is ignored.
    public void begin()
    {
      if (m_boards.size() > 0)
      {
        m_currentBoardIndex = 0;
        beginCurrentBoard();
      }
      else
      {
        onLastBoardCompleted();
      }
    }

    // Stops and rewinds.
    // Does not call completed handler.
    public void stop()
    {
      if (m_currentBoardIndex != -1)
      {
        Storyboard board = m_boards.get(m_currentBoardIndex);
        if (board != null)
        {
          board.Stop();
        }

        m_currentBoardIndex = -1;
      }
    }

    private void beginCurrentBoard()
    {
      Storyboard board = m_boards.get(m_currentBoardIndex);
      if (board == null)
      {
        onLastBoardCompleted();
      }
      else
      {
        board.Begin();
      }
    }

    // Triggered when the sequence completes.
    public event EventHandler Completed;

    private void onBoardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      m_currentBoardIndex++;

      if (m_currentBoardIndex >= m_boards.size())
      {
        onLastBoardCompleted();
      }
      else
      {
        beginCurrentBoard();
      }
    }

    private void onLastBoardCompleted()
    {
      m_currentBoardIndex = -1;
      Completed.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    private LinkedList<Storyboard> m_boards = new LinkedList<Storyboard>();

    // The current storyboard playing, or -1 if none.
    private int m_currentBoardIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the storyboard contains multiple animations they all get started at the same time and run simultaneously.  You can set the BeginTime property on the DoubleAnimations to a TimeSpan to indicate when they should begin...so by passing in an accumulative time of all the previous animations you should be able to get the sequential effect.

EDIT: Sorry - I just noticed the Silverlight tag. My answer works in WPF...I don't know about the differences between Silverlight and WPF animations.

[This](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/127163.aspx) might help. It looks like it is a difference between WPF and Silverlight. Where WPF can handle animating the same property on different animations in the same storyboard, Silverlight doesn't. Instead of having separate DoubleAnimations they suggest using a single DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames...then each of your separate animations becomes a key frame within it and it should animate linearly between them.

Comment: Never fear. This *is* relevant to SL as well. :)

Comment: I tried BeginTime but got the same error. Any other ideas? What's the correct way of doing sequential animations? Should I just string them together through completed event handlers and have a state variable in my code?

Comment: Did you have a look at the link I added at the end of my answer? It looks similar to what you're doing...and it's silverlight. ;-)

Comment: @swinefeaster forgot the ping

Comment: Thanks IanR, but using key frames didn't seem that straightforward, and I couldn't find any examples of how I would achieve this. The link you provided only asks the question again, but does not solve the answer. I have since implemented my own sequencer for storyboards, which I have included here. Thanks!

Comment: @swinefeaster That's odd - there was an answer there when I found it the other day...that's where I got the key frames idea. Glad you found a solution anyway.